# How big such set is?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Let $A \subset R$, where $R$ is the real line. Let $F=\{f\mid f: A\rightarrow R^\omega \text{ is continuous}\}$. How big is the set $F$? Thanks for your help.

Comment: "big. Really big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mindbogglingly big it is."

Comment: Think of the national debt...

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hitchhiker's guide rules!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are guaranteed of a countable dense subset $B \subset A$ since the reals are secound-countable (see the comments below).

Each $f$ is determined by its values at points in $B$, so $|F| \le |(\mathbb R^{\omega})^{B} | = \mathfrak c^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak c$

But each constant function is continuous, so $|F| \ge \mathfrak c$.  By Schroeder-Bernstein, $|F| = \mathfrak c$.

Comment: Not sure the first part is that simple. What if $A=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$?

Comment: All subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ are separable (follows from the second countability of $\mathbb{R}$), and so just use a countable dense subset of $F$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Ah! There we go. Although I suspect that Arthur meant a countable dense subset of $A$, rather than one of $F$.

Comment: In general, any subspace of a separable metric space is also separable.